# jQuery on.click does not work on dynamically loaded contet

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not very familiar with jQuery. I want to dynamically load a source.txt. Inside the source.txt is a button. These button should open a modal window. When I put the source.txt code inside the main.php, it works perfectly, but when I dynamically load the source.txt, then it does not work.

I used the on.click as a delegation, but it was not working as expected.

main.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).on("click","#link",function(){
 $("#include").load("http://www.damago.de/dev/source.txt"); 
});
$(document).on( "click","#opener", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:700,
      height:700,
      show: {
      },
      hide: {
      }
    });
 } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="include"></div>
        <a id="link" href="#">Include source.txt</a>
</body>
</html>


source.txt
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px;"src="/test.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: try something like this : $.ajax({
            url : "http://www.damago.de/dev/source.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#include").html(data);
            }
        });

Comment: can you try to put your code $(document).on("click","#link",function(){
 $("#include").load("http://www.damago.de/dev/source.txt"); 
});
$(document).on( "click","#opener", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });  inside the   $( function()  {   // put code here  });

Comment: 1. your `button` tag is invalid...didn't close properly. 2. that is outside html

Comment: your code is not affecting the DOM so there is no '#opener' item.

Comment: How can i Change it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Nothing of the above works.